# Delete Core data object and tablecell

Tags: ios, objective-c

i'm trying to delete an object in core data when you press swipe and press delete. The problem is it deletes the the tablecell, but when i go back and in again the deleted cells are back again. I guess thats because i only deleted the object in the NSMUtableArray (devices) and did not delete the core data object. How can i do this?

The saveTap where the objects are saved:

```
-(void)saveTap:(id)sender{
    Entity *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    [newManagedObject setValue:self.textfield.text forKey:@"playlistName"];
    [newManagedObject setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:selectedRowValue] forKey:@"idnumber"];



    // Save the context.
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![_managedObjectContext save:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();

    }

    [self fetchDevices];

    NSLog(@"COUNT %d", [devices count]);
}
```

and the commiteditingstyle method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:        (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [self.devices removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableViewData reloadData];    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; returning that NSManagedObject you want to delete?
Then you should make the second function like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:        (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [_managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [_managedObjectContext save:nil];
        [self.devices removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableViewData reloadData];    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reloading while of UitableView you should only reloadrowatindexpaths: and before it [UITableView beganEditing];
And after Reloading rows
[UITableView endEditing];